# No scanners detected

Tags: applications

Running elementary OS freya 0.3.1 Freya with network printer HP Photosmart 7520 All-In-One Inkjet Printer/Copier/Scanner/Fax.

Printer works fine.

When I invoke Simple Scan to scan a document, the following error is displayed:

```
No scanners detected
```

Please check your scanner is connected and powered on

Comment: Have you installed any additional drivers for it?

Comment: @r3bl It's shouldn't be necessary. According to the [HPLIP-Database](http://hplipopensource.com/hplip-web/models/photosmart/photosmart_7520_series.html) HP Photosmart 7520 should be fully supported since version 3.12.9. elementary OS provides version 3.14.3

Comment: Please check if `libsane-hpaio` is installed. You can do it with running the following command in your terminal: `dpkg -l | grep libsane-hpaio`. If it's not installed, install it with `sudo apt-get install libsane-hpaio`.

Comment: @Rafael Output of dpkg -l command indicates libsane-hpaio is installed.

Comment: I have the same problem with HP ENVY 4502 this very same printer scans and prints fine with other distros (ubuntu,linux lite,mint) on a network connection,only elementary fails to recognize scannner. This is what I get on terminal when I tried to reinstall ```hplip```: Reading package lists... Done Building dependency tree Reading state information... Done libsane-hpaio is already the newest version. 0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.

Comment: still no solution for this problem with elementary OS after many months :(
ubuntu,mint,linux lite all work fine ????

Answer (score 1):

If I do a direct connection to my HP Officejet Pro L7590 via USB, the printer is immediately recognized as a scanner as well. So, contrary to HP's own documentation, this seems to be a limitation of libsane-hpaio when trying to use over a wired network. This is the only way I have managed to get this to work.

Answer (score 0):

Remove printer from system settings.

Run

```
hp-setup -u
```

Comment: You haven't explained what the command does or what the flag does.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem with my hp deskjet 2540 which I solved the following way:

1. Make sure you have the hplip installed
2. open `system-config-printer` from the command line
3. Add the printer again (I called it "Scanner") and make sure you use the `HP JetDirect` Connection not IPP

Afterwards, I was able to scan even over wifi. Same trick worked on a Mint machine as well.